# Regular Expressions in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

How do I trim leading zeros and trailing zeros using rereplace?

It has something to do with a caret and a star and a dollar sign.

And a 0.

Here's a cheat sheet:
http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/

Comment: Is this a trick question?  Why don't you just use the cheat sheet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
reReplace(string, "^0*(.*?)0*$", "$1", "ALL")
```

That is:

```
^ = starting with
0* = the character "0", zero or more times
() = capture group, referenced later as $1
.* = any character, zero or more times
*? = zero or more, but lazy matching; try not to match the next character
0* = the character "0", zero or more times, this time at the end
$ = end of the string
```

Comment: upboated for outstanding decision to include explanation.

Comment: The $ in the replacement string should be a \ (tested in Railo 4.1.2.005)

Answer (score 4):

```
<cfset newValue = REReplace(value, "^0+|0+$", "", "ALL")>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a coldfusion expert, but something like, replace all ^0+ and 0+$ by empty string, e.g.:

```
REReplace("000xyz000","^0+|0+$","")
```

Comment: That's a sweet link, morja.  I think you need the "all" as a 3rd parameter in REReplace.

Comment: Ok, as I said, I am not an expert in coldfusion ;)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.. would check for your use cases.

```
<cfset sTest= "0001" />
<cfset sTest= "leading zeros? 0001" />
<cfset sTest= "leading zeros? 0001.02" />
<cfset sTest= "leading zeros? 0001." />
<cfset sTest= "leading zeros? 0001.2" />

<cfset sResult= reReplace( sTest , "0+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)" , "\1" , "all" ) />
```

Answer (score 1):

The above does not work at all, except bradley's answer!

In ColdFusion, to reference a capture group, you need `\` instead of `$`, e.g. `\1` instead of `$1`.

So the correct answer is:

```
reReplace(string, "^0*(.*?)0*$", "\1", "ALL")
```

That is:

```
^  = starting with
0* = the character "0", zero or more times
() = capture group, referenced later as $1
.* = any character, zero or more times
*? = zero or more, but lazy matching; try not to match the next character
0* = the character "0", zero or more times, this time at the end
$  = end of the string
```

And:

```
\1 reference to capture group 1  (see above, introduced by ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old but I'm posting in case anyone finds it useful. I have found myself needing to trim custom characters on multiple occasions so I want to share a recent helper I wrote to trim any custom character using rereplace if you find it useful. It works just like regular trim but you can pass any custom character string as the 2nd param and it will trim all leading/trailing characters.

```
   /**
    * Trims leading and trailing characters using rereplace
    * @param string - string to trim
    * @param string- custom character to trim
    * @return string - result
    */
    function $trim(required string, string customChar=" "){
        var result = arguments.string;

        var char = len(arguments.customChar) ? left(arguments.customChar, 1) : ' ';

        char = reEscape(char);

        result = REReplace(result, "#char#+$", "", "ALL");
        result = REReplace(result, "^#char#+", "", "ALL");

        return result;
    }
```

In your case you can just use this helper to do something like:

```
string = "0000foobar0000";
string = $trim(string, "0");
//string now "foobar"
```

hope this helps someone :)